# How can I improve my javascript pattern for greater flexibility/maintainability?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture

Currently I load all my javascript with a pattern similar to the code below. One file would reflect a single page or component in a site. For example, if I had a contact page the associated javascript file might be:

```
(function () {

    $(function () {
        contactForm.init();
        locationMap.init();
    });

    var contactForm = {

        init: function () {
            ... Do form manipulation here
        }
    };

    var locationMap = {

        init: function () {
            ... Do map manipulation here
        }
    };

})();
```

This is fine for smaller sites but as a site grows and functionality needs to be shared across pages or certain components develop a reliance on each other (e.g. the options in the contact form might change based upon the selection location map) this pattern shows it's limitations.

My question is, how can I improve this to allow for growing complexity and reliance between modules?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough to post an answer on this - but have you considered using AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition), through an implementation such as require.js or curl.js. One of the goals of this technology is to handle requirements management and re-use.

Comment: Thanks @james, I had considered require.js but wanted to get a better understanding of how I could improve my own code first.

Comment: I would strongly suggest: **step up**, use some of the improved languages on top of the JavaScript. I/we've choosen TypeScript. E.g. I cannot compare prev JS maintainace and current **TypeScript** based. It comes with architectural features as *The Revealing Module* (you've partially tried to use) and many more. But with support of some IDE it could do even the compile time checking... That would be my strong suggestion...

Comment: I wrote about improving your architecture through dependency management on my JavaScript blog, here: http://jsforallof.us/2014/08/01/package-management-and-dependency-management/ specifically using Browserify to handle dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good improvement will be organizing your code in namespaces and use The Revealing Module pattern:

```
var contact = contact || {};
var contact.form = (function () {
    // private functions
    function privateFunction() {}        
    // public functions
    function init() {
        privateFunction()
        ... Do form manipulation here
    }

    return {
        init : init
    };
})();
```

but for more complex applications i suggest to look for some MVVM architecture framework (i prefer [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/))

Answer (score 1):

You should use a module loader, like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/). By requirejs you have to use AMD style module definitions, by browserify you have to use commonjs style module definitions. Commonjs is not compatible with browsers by default (it is for nodejs), so you have to build browser compatible js files from it (browserify does that). In your case requirejs might be a better solution (if you are not familiar with nodejs), but I suggest you read more about both.

Another possible solution is using [ES6 modules](http://eviltrout.com/2014/05/03/getting-started-with-es6.html). Currently you have to build by them as well, but later they will be supported by every browser I think.